# How to add parameters in direct add_to_cart URL in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I'm trying to take from an elementor form some user input data to the checkout page, to let it automatically fill the checkout fields.

I've used the url: https://mywebsite.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=49&quantity=1 as redirection URL after the form submission... and I correctly get the add to cart by URL redirection.

I've also created a PHP script (insert in functions.php) to get some parameters from URL to autofill the checkout fields... and this also works perfectly
Here an example of the Checkout URL with the parameters:
https://mywebsite.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=549&quantity=1&ga_em=EMAIL@TEST.COM&ga_nm=NOME&ga_sr=COGNOME&ga_ph=222222222

But, if I merge both, i get only the add_to_cart action but not the autofill. Here the full link that I used:
https://mywebsite.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=49&quantity=1&ga_em=EMAIL@TEST.COM&ga_nm=NOME&ga_sr=COGNOME&ga_ph=222222222

When go to that URL, i obtain the add_to_cart (not the autofill) and also I see all the URL parameters cleaned and the URL become just https://mywebsite.com/checkout/

Comment: Other than that the value of the `add-to-cart` parameter is different, there does not appear to be any significant difference between the 2nd and 3rd URL you have shown. _"I've also created a PHP script (insert in functions.php) to [...]"_ - show actual relevant code for that please.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the user data from URL to Woocommerce session by using the filter

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'set_custom_data_wc_session' );
```

After this you can get the data from the session using

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields' , 'prefill_billing_fields' );
function prefill_billing_fields ( $address_fields ) {
// Get the session data
$data = WC()->session->get('custom_data');
...
}
```

Comment: i've already done it in functions.php... and the autofill fields in checkout is working, but only in my URL there isn't the ?add_to_cart=49&quantity=1... otherwise, i get only the add to cart action and the fields don't get filled